# SharedPreferences not Automatically Saving?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

My preference values aren't saving and everytime I read the SharedPreferences file it returns default values; changes are supposed to be automatically handled by the system when a user makes a choice (like selecting an option in a `ListPreference`) so I don't know why this isn't happening in my app.

According to [google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Overview)

*"When the user changes a setting, the system updates the corresponding value in the SharedPreferences file for you. The only time you should directly interact with the associated SharedPreferences file is when you need to read the value in order to determine your app's behavior based on the user's setting."*

Should I be manipulating a `SharedPreference.Editor` instance in my `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` or is there something else I need to do to make values of user settings persist?

**The Problem in Code:** As a result of this misunderstanding, my code doesn't persist user settings values (the default value is always chosen when I read the SharedPreference file in my MainActivity's OnCreate). As it is now, the buttons chosen in my Preferences menu View persist upon app restarts, but it seems that choosing an option in this menu doesn't save key values to the SharedPreferences file.

What do I need to do to make the values set by the user in my ListPreference persist?

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private static int prefWoodColor;   //saved pref variable for OpenGL neck texture
        private SharedPreferences settings;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            //Restore preferences
            settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            prefWoodColor = Integer.parseInt(settings.getString(this.KEY_PREF_WOOD_TYPE, "Maple")); 
            ...
        }
    }
```

**Preferences Activity**

```
public class FragmentSettingsMenu extends com.takisoft.fix.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from the XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if (key.equals("pref_wood")) {
                    Preference woodPref = findPreference(key);
                    String color = woodPref.getSharedPreferences().getString(key, "Maple");
                    //Should I be calling edit.apply() logic here? 
                }
            }
        };
    }
    ...

}
```

**Preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:title="Settings"
    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_wood"
        android:title="@string/pref_wood"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_wood"
        android:entries="@array/pref_wood_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_wood_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_wood_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
    <string name="dummy_button">Dummy Button</string>
    <string name="dummy_content">DUMMY\nCONTENT</string>

     <!--Preference Menu Strings-->
    <string name="pref_wood">Wood Style</string>
    <string-array name="pref_wood_entries">
        <item>"Maple"</item>
        <item>"Cedar"</item>
        <item>"Oak"</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pref_wood_values">
        <item >0</item>
        <item >1</item>
        <item >2</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="pref_wood_default">Maple</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: The system saves it for you. Check that the preference key matches correctly between code and XML. Also, if your default value is "Maple" it doesn't make sense to be parsing the value into an int.

Comment: @samgak Check the updated edits, i've included my preferences.xml file so you can see that there are no mismatches (as far as I can tell). I use a strings.xml file to specify values for each option in my ListPreference so parsing it is an integer does make sense, since i've programmed my code to update wood textures based on number codes instead of strings.

Comment: The default value should be the default from the entryValues array, not entries (in your case it would be "0")

Comment: @samgak Which line of code are you saying should be changed? Also, I don't think this will fix the issue of values not saving/reading properly.

Comment: The parameter to getString. And you're right it won't fix the saving/reading issue. Is this.KEY_PREF_WOOD_TYPE equal to "pref_wood"?

Comment: Yes, it equals "pref_wood".

Answer (score 1):

The system saves changes automatically!

Comment: So can you explain why my code is seeing the default value everytime I read  the preferences file in my MainActivity's OnCreate()?

Comment: Because you are doing like this:  settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: Make onResume, but without getting default pref.

Comment: Is there some other way to intialize my settings variable, other than calling getDefaultSharedPreferences()? Perhaps you can explain with code.